# Remove borders from geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to plot boxplots without the horrible black borders. I managed to find a workaround:

```
library(ggplot2)
my_data <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100,0,1), group = rep(c("A","B"), each =50))
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = group1, y = y, fill = group, color = group1)) +geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Is this the correct way? This way I'm drawing the borders with the same color used for the fill, but I was wondering if it was possible to not draw them at all.

Comment: Do you want to keep the median line?

Comment: Maybe try `ggplot(my_data, aes(x = group, y = y)) + ggthemes::geom_tufteboxplot()` to retain the information.

Comment: @aosmith yes, that would be nice! A white median line, if it is possible. If it's impossible, I'll have to live without.

Comment: See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46015146/removing-the-borders-in-geom-boxplot-in-ggplot2/46016360#46016360

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it by inspecting the grid element.

```
library(grid); library(ggplot2)
box <- ggplot(iris, aes(y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot()

#box
grid.draw(box) # drawing the grid for the box plot
grid.force() 
# grid.ls() # this is needed to find what the element is called in this grid (you can do this with any specific element)

# grid.edit("geom_polygon.polygon.2827", gp = gpar(col = NA)) # here we are targeting a single element

grid.edit("geom_polygon.polygon*", gp = gpar(col = NA), grep = T, global = T) # getting rid of the rectangles on the boxplots
grid.edit("GRID.rect*", gp = gpar(col = NA), grep = T, global = T) # rect's on the legend
```