# Remove borders from geom_boxplot in a plot with multiple plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm trying to remove the borders from a `geom_boxplot` which I plotted in one plot with a  back-to-back barchart (see first figure below). I tried two solutions suggested in this post on stackoverflow: [Removing the borders in geom_boxplot in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46015146/removing-the-borders-in-geom-boxplot-in-ggplot2/46016360#46016360). I couldn't make the first solution by Z.Lin work because my data structure is very different, i.e. I have two dataframes that I get data from for my plot (see code example below). The second solution by Marco Sandri using `ggplotGrob()`produced a better result, as the borders of the boxplot aren't black anymore, but there still is a border around my boxplot, yet in two different colors (the upper border is a brighter grey, lower one is a darker grey). Essentially, I want the borders to disappear so that the only colour I can see in the boxplot is the grey inside the boxplots borders.

[image]

Here is my data and code for my `ggplot()` that you can see in the figure above:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")


#data 
        plotting_df <- structure(list(lower = c(2600, 2800, 3000, 3200, 3400, 3600, 
            3800, 4000, 4200, 4400, 4600, 4800, 5000, 5200, 5400, 5600, 5800, 
            6000, 6200, 6400, 6600, 6800, 2600, 2800, 3000, 3200, 3400, 3600, 
            3800, 4000, 4200, 4400, 4600, 4800, 5000, 5200, 5400, 5600, 5800, 
            6000, 6200, 6400, 6600, 6800), upper = c(2800, 3000, 3200, 3400, 
            3600, 3800, 4000, 4200, 4400, 4600, 4800, 5000, 5200, 5400, 5600, 
            5800, 6000, 6200, 6400, 6600, 6800, 7000, 2800, 3000, 3200, 3400, 
            3600, 3800, 4000, 4200, 4400, 4600, 4800, 5000, 5200, 5400, 5600, 
            5800, 6000, 6200, 6400, 6600, 6800, 7000), Height_range = c("2600 - <2800", 
            "2800 - <3000", "3000 - <3200", "3200 - <3400", "3400 - <3600", 
            "3600 - <3800", "3800 - <4000", "4000 - <4200", "4200 - <4400", 
            "4400 - <4600", "4600 - <4800", "4800 - <5000", "5000 - <5200", 
            "5200 - <5400", "5400 - <5600", "5600 - <5800", "5800 - <6000", 
            "6000 - <6200", "6200 - <6400", "6400 - <6600", "6600 - <6800", 
            "6800 - <7000", "2600 - <2800", "2800 - <3000", "3000 - <3200", 
            "3200 - <3400", "3400 - <3600", "3600 - <3800", "3800 - <4000", 
            "4000 - <4200", "4200 - <4400", "4400 - <4600", "4600 - <4800", 
            "4800 - <5000", "5000 - <5200", "5200 - <5400", "5400 - <5600", 
            "5600 - <5800", "5800 - <6000", "6000 - <6200", "6200 - <6400", 
            "6400 - <6600", "6600 - <6800", "6800 - <7000"), Area_perc = c(0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0171998035286124, -0.391830350037395, 
            -1.42005343063345, -6.61927165249893, -12.132450467133, -14.1336176577804, 
            -17.2832354114005, -25.0060327669093, -16.4868246082124, -3.87722934269368, 
            -1.92517999893892, -0.570759649432064, -0.136314860801391, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0.0784180266027078, 0.145942159727887, 1.19535722067067, 
            4.20054127345113, 7.41856139384216, 12.6149485826234, 21.9427323325356, 
            24.6268616403503, 16.3830653075409, 8.45600217517741, 2.20038641810583, 
            0.680643261901804, 0.0565402074701498, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Umgebung = c("Glacial", 
            "Glacial", "Glacial", "Glacial", "Glacial", "Glacial", "Glacial", 
            "Glacial", "Glacial", "Glacial", "Glacial", "Glacial", "Glacial", 
            "Glacial", "Glacial", "Glacial", "Glacial", "Glacial", "Glacial", 
            "Glacial", "Glacial", "Glacial", "Periglacial", "Periglacial", 
            "Periglacial", "Periglacial", "Periglacial", "Periglacial", "Periglacial", 
            "Periglacial", "Periglacial", "Periglacial", "Periglacial", "Periglacial", 
            "Periglacial", "Periglacial", "Periglacial", "Periglacial", "Periglacial", 
            "Periglacial", "Periglacial", "Periglacial", "Periglacial", "Periglacial"
            )), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
            -44L), groups = structure(list(Height_range = c("2600 - <2800", 
            "2600 - <2800", "2800 - <3000", "2800 - <3000", "3000 - <3200", 
            "3000 - <3200", "3200 - <3400", "3200 - <3400", "3400 - <3600", 
            "3400 - <3600", "3600 - <3800", "3600 - <3800", "3800 - <4000", 
            "3800 - <4000", "4000 - <4200", "4000 - <4200", "4200 - <4400", 
            "4200 - <4400", "4400 - <4600", "4400 - <4600", "4600 - <4800", 
            "4600 - <4800", "4800 - <5000", "4800 - <5000", "5000 - <5200", 
            "5000 - <5200", "5200 - <5400", "5200 - <5400", "5400 - <5600", 
            "5400 - <5600", "5600 - <5800", "5600 - <5800", "5800 - <6000", 
            "5800 - <6000", "6000 - <6200", "6000 - <6200", "6200 - <6400", 
            "6200 - <6400", "6400 - <6600", "6400 - <6600", "6600 - <6800", 
            "6600 - <6800", "6800 - <7000", "6800 - <7000"), Umgebung = c("Glacial", 
            "Periglacial", "Glacial", "Periglacial", "Glacial", "Periglacial", 
            "Glacial", "Periglacial", "Glacial", "Periglacial", "Glacial", 
            "Periglacial", "Glacial", "Periglacial", "Glacial", "Periglacial", 
            "Glacial", "Periglacial", "Glacial", "Periglacial", "Glacial", 
            "Periglacial", "Glacial", "Periglacial", "Glacial", "Periglacial", 
            "Glacial", "Periglacial", "Glacial", "Periglacial", "Glacial", 
            "Periglacial", "Glacial", "Periglacial", "Glacial", "Periglacial", 
            "Glacial", "Periglacial", "Glacial", "Periglacial", "Glacial", 
            "Periglacial", "Glacial", "Periglacial"), .rows = structure(list(
                1L, 23L, 2L, 24L, 3L, 25L, 4L, 26L, 5L, 27L, 6L, 28L, 7L, 
                29L, 8L, 30L, 9L, 31L, 10L, 32L, 11L, 33L, 12L, 34L, 13L, 
                35L, 14L, 36L, 15L, 37L, 16L, 38L, 17L, 39L, 18L, 40L, 19L, 
                41L, 20L, 42L, 21L, 43L, 22L, 44L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
            "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
            ), row.names = c(NA, -44L), .drop = TRUE))

df_ZDI_DA <- structure(list(elev_ZDI = c(4242.45072720705, 4025.36851525495, 
4490.42784012889, 4419.33695496036, 4456.61786982558, 4424.13956691806, 
4519.97092904702, 4134.61730468713, 4538.15301716998, 4548.14527849092, 
4426.69407980544, 4413.57219115039, 4286.54383264672, 4226.88999622552, 
4872.17946504459, 4838.93553055335, 5100.53490596391, 4528.37548467866, 
4782.34008360883, 4799.61192931735, 4825.81569965177, 4767.07951578108, 
4908.10303692811, 4943.09894614945, 4800.6726732299, 4636.69410725579, 
4802.85980093967, 4871.61228244457, 4770.48281915333, 4713.98556387196, 
4635.9659563796, 4566.82347497361, 4516.52484757333, 4482.02451025631, 
4836.07642186679, 4853.72631589253, 4895.54006606894, 4762.82371573422, 
5090.7671665217, 5091.5915478948, 5032.31248860355, 4911.03124033477, 
4876.71482393121, 4859.7735910215, 4964.82526118134, 4795.78714207257, 
5074.38982472751, 5055.56189192946, 4946.96820293933, 4913.6253457149, 
4865.18365695523, 4754.85074207502, 4741.96253705904, 4714.73266080364, 
4668.57592153896, 5035.5104982935, 4945.11227401406, 4930.27013232857, 
4899.27094179511, 4765.3909734884, 4683.71613590778, 5074.81149535519, 
5051.53351572249, 5029.46687088302, 4991.164391363, 5087.58168306149, 
5061.77293735475, 5035.29841844616, 5027.22671401651), Area_perc = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "0", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-69L))

#code for ggplot

plot_DA <- plotting_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(ygroup = Umgebung, fill = Umgebung)) +
  geom_boxplot(data = df_ZDI_DA, aes(y = elev_ZDI), inherit.aes = FALSE, 
               width = 65, color = "black", fill = "grey", alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = lower + 10, ymax = upper - 10, xmin = 0, xmax = Area_perc)) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq(-35, 35, 10),
    labels = abs(seq(-35, 35, 10)),
    limits = c(-35, 35), expand = c(0, 0)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(3000, 7000, 1000)) + 
  labs(x = "Area [%]", y = "Elevation [m. a.s.l.]" , title = "Desert Andes") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) + # reverse order of items in legend
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("#AD355D", "#440A68"), # change colors of bars
    name = "",
    breaks = c("Periglacial", "Glacial"),
    labels = c("Periglacial", "Glacial")
  ) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5, b = 0, l = 0)), # move y-axis title further away from axis labels
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  ) 

plot_DA
```

Answer (score 0):

One option to remove the borders would be to set the line width to 0 four your boxplot and if required add the median line via e.g. an additional `stat_summary` layer:

```
library(ggplot2)

bp_width <- 65
ggplot(plotting_df, aes(ygroup = Umgebung, fill = Umgebung)) +
  geom_boxplot(
    data = df_ZDI_DA, aes(y = elev_ZDI), inherit.aes = FALSE,
    width = 65, color = "black", fill = "grey", alpha = 0.6,
    linewidth = 0
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    data = df_ZDI_DA,
    aes(
      x = -bp_width / 2,
      xend = +bp_width / 2,
      y = elev_ZDI,
      yend = after_stat(y)
    ), fun = median, geom = "segment", inherit.aes = FALSE, linewidth = 1
  ) +
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = lower + 10, ymax = upper - 10, xmin = 0, xmax = Area_perc)) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq(-35, 35, 10),
    labels = abs(seq(-35, 35, 10)),
    limits = c(-35, 35), expand = c(0, 0)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(3000, 7000, 1000)) +
  labs(x = "Area [%]", y = "Elevation [m. a.s.l.]", title = "Desert Andes") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) + # reverse order of items in legend
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("#AD355D", "#440A68"), # change colors of bars
    name = "",
    breaks = c("Periglacial", "Glacial"),
    labels = c("Periglacial", "Glacial")
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5, b = 0, l = 0)), # move y-axis title further away from axis labels
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I just ran the code, it still produces the black lines though. Am I missing something?

Comment: Might be an issue with your ggplot2 version. The `linewidth` aes was introduced with ggplot2 3.4.0. If you run on an older version if will not have an effect. In that case you could replace it with `size` or check your ggplot2 version and update.

Comment: Hm, I checked on three different machines, all of them run the latest version of `ggplot` and R and all of them have the same issue... Guess I'll have to do some digging why this happens. As soon as the problem is resolved I'll of course mark your answer as correct!

Comment: Hm. Weird. I just checked again in a clean and fresh R session. And works fine on my side. ):